# ShowDialog hiding objects when called

Tags: c#, visible, showdialog

I'm running into a very weird problem that I'm at a loss about.  I have a form that has two buttons on it (`button1` and `button2` for this purpose).  In the click events for these buttons a new instance of a form is created and then shown as a dialog.

```
private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmPanel1 panel1 = new frmPanel1();
    panel1.ShowDialog(this);
}
private void button2_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmPanel2 panel2 = new frmPanel2();
    panel2.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

Everything works fine for `button1`, the modal appears just fine.  For `button2`, when I click on it the objects on the `this` form disappear before the modal is shown.  I tried to set the visible state of the parent object to true and then immediately put a messagebox in to check the visible state and it shows as false.

Everything about `frmPanel1` and `frmPanel2` property-wise is the same, there is nothing obvious jumping out at me.  Any thoughts on this, any suggestions on how to debug or I'd even settle for forcing the visible state back to true.

Comment: Try clicking button2 first and then button1 and see If it works correctly.

Comment: Something on `frmPanel2` is probably doing a lot of work in the UI thread, causing the background form to stop painting while that form is open. Without seeing the code to `frmPanel2`, I can't say what. To see if thats the problem, replace `frmPane2 panel2 = new frmPanel2();` with `Form panel2 = new Form();` and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: Is this Winforms or WPF? Please tag accordingly!

Answer (score 1):

Oh Moses smell the roses.  Found the problem here, I apparently pasted some code where I shouldn't have or was drunk or something.  At the top of the class for frmPanel2 I had a line that declared a local instance of the parent objects class - i.e.

```
frmMain main = new frmMain();
```

Why/When I did that is anyone's guess.  Many thanks to kanchirk and Ron Beyer for their suggestions, they both helped greatly to narrow down the problem to what was ultimately something inane.  Thanks.

erik